# Issue utilizing Keys:Values from Dict with da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, dictionary

I have a field that holds a variety of strings. These strings were field names and corresponding values that were concatenated into a single field per feature. Using .split/indexing I was able to create a dictionary where values correspond to field names and values correspond to attributes.

attributes in field=   '"xyz"="abc","ghi"="lmno"'

```
dict= {'xyz':'abc','ghi':'lmno'}
```

I am now at the point where I'm trying to feed the keys:values into a da.UpdateCursor where the key is the field and row= value. Block below is the last part of the script I'm struggling with. I keep getting an error: sequence size must match size of row.

```
i= 0
z= 0
n= 0

while i <= getCount:
    kI= dic.keys()[z]
    kiS= str(kI)
    vI= dic.values()[n]

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(item,kiS)as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row= vI
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            i+= 1
            z+= 1
            n+= 1
```

Comment: It looks like it's at row = vI, it should be something like row[n] = vI. I would use the dictionary as-is rather than iterating as all your features would have the last value in the dictionary.

Comment: Clobbering the row variable is very inappropriate.

Comment: Also should point out that you define your dictionary as `dict` yet refer to it as `dic` later on in your while loop. It's also not a good idea to call your dictionary 'dict' because it is a python key word.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I attempted earlier to use the row[n] with no success. And although I used dict for the written portion above it is referenced as dic throughout the extent of the written script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're trying to do something like this:

```
dict= {'xyz':'abc','ghi':'lmno'}

for key in dict.iterkeys():
    print key + "=" + dict[key]
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(item,key) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = dict[key]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Updating each field with the value stored against it in the dictonary.. It would be better to update each field in the row in turn and store once:

```
dict= {'xyz':'abc','ghi':'lmno'}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(item,list(dict.iterkeys())) as uCur: # list(dict.iterkeys()) is ['xyz','ghi']
    fRange = range(len(dict))    # range to iterate - in this case [0,1]
    fVals  = list(dict.values()) # list of values   - in ths case ['abc','lmno']
    for row in UCur:
        for Index in fRange:     # update each field by index in the lists
            row[Index] = fVals[Index]
        UCur.updateRow(row)
```

As the slowest part is the storing of the row this will work much quicker.

Comment: thanks so much. I'll try first thing tomorrow when get access to a computer with arc on it. I'll be sure to accept this as soon as I can.

Comment: Just create a list outside of the for loop. It never changes because the field order is static...

Comment: After running it hit an error stating for Index in fRange: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Although I'm not sure of the hit on performance for doing this, prior I was able to run using while..in this case it would look like Index= 0 while Index <= fRange: row[Index]=fVals[Index] Index +=1. Will try to update with this later today unless you think there may be a way that will perform it better. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the range keyword. len(dict) returns an int which is not iterable but range(len(dict)) returns a range from 0 to the length of the dict minus one. I've fixed that in the code.